# VB Check if Multiselect in Listbox

Tags: vb.net

Simple thing: How can I check if the user has selected more than one Item in a ListBox? I tried it like this:

```
If listbox.SelectedItems(1) Then ...
```

But it returned an out of range exception...

THX for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have now is attempting to access the second item in the `SelectedItems` collection, which holds all of the currently selected items in the `ListBox`. This is because the default property of `SelectedItems` is [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedobjectcollection.item.aspx), which accepts the zero-based index of an item as a parameter. You are getting an "out of range exception" because there are less than two items currently selected, which means there is no value to return at index = 1.

Instead, to check if the user has selected more than one item, you need to use the [`Count` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedobjectcollection.count.aspx) of the `SelectedItems` collection. For example:

```
If listbox.SelectedItems.Count > 1 Then
    ''#your code here
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If listbox.SelectedItems.Count() > 1 Then
```